# Amplitude of sum of telescopic sum of scaled sines

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following series
$$
f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k\cos(\omega^kt + k\phi)
$$
with $0 < a < 1$, $\omega \geq 1$, and $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there an expression for the amplitude $A$?

From the sum of the geometric progression, it follows that
$$A \leq \frac{1}{1 - a}$$
However, if $\phi = \pi$ the amplitude could be smaller due to destructive inference. In the case there is no closed form of the amplitude, is there a better upper bound than the one given by the geometric progression.

Comment: By amplitude, do you mean $A=\sup_t|f(t)|$?

Comment: @MengchunZhang, yes

Comment: For $\omega=1$, we have $f(t)=\text{Re}\big(e^{it}\sum_k(ae^{i\phi})^k\big)=\text{Re}\big(e^{it}/(1-ae^{i\phi})\big)$, hence $A\leq|1-ae^{i\phi}|^{-1}$. You can improve the bound by explicitly calculating the real part, but it could be tedious. As for $\omega>1$, maybe the same idea can provide something, but I am not sure for now.

Comment: Is this reasonable

$\left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 2a\cos\left(\phi\right) + 1}}
 {a^2 - 2 a \cos\left(\phi \right) + 1}\right|$

Comment: Sorry, should be 
$\left|\frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 2a\cos\left(\phi\right) + 1}}
 {a^2 - 2 a \cos\left(\phi \right) + 1}\right|$, I guess.

Comment: For $\omega=1$, yes your bound is reasonable. In fact this bound is sharp since $f(t)=|1-ae^{i\phi}|^{-1}$ when $t=(1-ae^{i\phi})/|1-ae^{i\phi}|$.